# django/drf: many-to-many, serializer, duplicates

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I have M2M relationship between models Combo and ComboLinks.

User should be able to provide ComboLinks that are gathered by the backend into a one Combo.
This is done with through DRF serializer and it works but with an issue: if a user provides a list of ComboLinks that has one or more ComboLinks already present in the database - duplicate is created.

How can I avoid creating those duplicates and use already present ComboLinks to point to new Combo object?

django model structure:

```
class Combo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='searches')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class ComboLink(models.Model):
    combo = models.ManyToManyField('Combo', blank=True, related_name='links')
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 64, null=True, blank=True)
```

django view:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def getCombo(request, pk=None):
    user = request.user
    # for all paths besides create new search
    if (pk != 'new') and (pk != None):
        combo = Combo.objects.get(id=int(pk))
        if user != combo.user:
            return Response('Not valid user for a search', status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    
    # handle different request methods 
    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = ComboSerializer(combo, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.data
        data['user'] = user.id
        combo = Combo.objects.create(user= User.objects.get(id=user.id))

        serializer = ComboSerializer(instance = combo, data = data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            print('updateSearch: combo serializer IS valid')
            serializer.save()
            combo.save()
        else:
            print('updateSearch: combo serializer NOT valid, failing to save')
            print(serializer.errors)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

serializers (writeable):

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, HyperlinkedRelatedField
from drf_writable_nested.serializers import WritableNestedModelSerializer
from .models import ComboLink, Combo

class ComboLinkSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ComboLink
        fields = ['title']


class ComboSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    links = ComboLinkSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Combo
        fields = ['user', 'id', 'updated','links']
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to abandon saving through DRF serializer because if I link manually existing ComboLinks but pass to serializer.save only new ones then only new ones will be saved since it overwrites data:/
So, only use serializer to verify format and save manually everything

```
        def check_links(request, combo=None):
        """ if provided link was already present in the db just use it instead of creating a duplicate """
        data = request.data.copy()
        data['user'] = user.id
        if not combo:
            combo = Combo.objects.create(user=request.user)


        for indx, i in enumerate(data['links']):
            if ComboLink.objects.filter(link=i['link']).exists():
                cl = ComboLink.objects.get(link=i['link'])
            else:
                cl = ComboLink.objects.create(title=i['title'], link=i['link'], img=i['img'])
            combo.links.add(cl)

        serializer = ComboSerializer(instance = combo, data = data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print('updateSearch: combo serializer IS valid')
            combo.save()
        else:
            print('updateSearch: combo serializer NOT valid, failing to save')
            print(serializer.errors)
        return serializer.data
```